# Prove that $N(a+b\xi)=\frac{a^5+b^5}{a+b}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Let $\xi=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}$, and let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ be a number field. I want to prove that $N(a+b\xi)=\frac{a^5+b^5}{a+b}$, where $a+b\neq0$.

If I define the $4$ inmersion like this: $\sigma_j(\xi)=\xi^j$, where $j=1,\ldots,4$, then I  think I could start by computing $\sigma_1(a+b\xi)\sigma_4(a+b\xi)$ and $\sigma_2(a+b\xi)\sigma_3(a+b\xi)$, and finally multiplying them together.

$$\sigma_1(a+b\xi)\sigma_4(a+b\xi)=a^2+b^2+ab(\xi+\xi^4)$$
$$\sigma_2(a+b\xi)\sigma_3(a+b\xi)=a^2+b^2+ab(\xi^2+\xi^3)$$
I know that $(\xi+\xi^4)=2Re(\xi)$, where $Re$ denotes the real part. However this doesn't help much. If I multiply them together I get a very long expression which doesn't ressemble the one I am aiming to. I've also tried some geometric arguments but I cannot get to the solution. Can someone help me?

Comment: Note $\prod(x-\xi^i)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is the cyclotomic polynomial.

Comment: @KentaS I am aware of that but I not sure how can that help me here

Comment: By definition if $K>L$ is a finite Galois extensions, and $\phi_1,...,\phi_n$ are the automorphisms of $K$ over $L$ then the norm $|x|_L$ of an element $x\in K$ is $\phi_1(x)\cdot ...\cdot \phi_n(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
N(a+b\xi)&=\prod_{i=1}^4(a+b\xi^i)\\
&=(-b)^4\prod_{i=1}^4\left(-\frac ab-\xi^i\right)\\
&=b^4\Phi_5\left(-\frac ab\right).
\end{align*}